# Doubling Internet Connection Speed

Tags: networking

Scenario: I have two ADSL modem that are connected to to different ISPs. Each has 256KBps Speed.
Question:Is it possible to have 512KBps speed?(I have one PC that can be host any OS)
Is any special appliance essential for doing that?

Thanks in Advance,
Ashkan.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://serverfault.com (ServerFault).  Or even http://superuser.com (SuperUser)

Answer (score 3):

This is called [multihoming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) or **load-balancing**.

The simplest way to do this would be to buy a router with two WAN ports that supports load balancing. These are generally expensive.

Alternatively you can set up a computer with 3 network interfaces to do the routing for you.

### Windows

Using regedit navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters
```

Create 32-bit dword value "RandomAdapter" with a value of 1

You will need to set the "metric" value of the different adapters if you find traffic is still favouring one connection over the other.

From my [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/114735/how-to-configure-2-lan-cards/114736) on serverfault, the
"[route](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx)" command is used to set this metric. The basic syntax is;

```
 route ADD <destination> <subnet mask> <gateway (vpn dhcp server)> <metrix> IF <interface number> -p
```

There's some tutorials floating around [here](http://www.tech-faq.com/windows-routing-table.shtml) and [there](http://www.petri.co.il/configuring_routing_in_w2k_pro_xp_pro.htm).

### Linux

See the answers on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=linux+load+balancing)

Comment: +1, I voted to move this to SU, but nice answer.

Comment: Which one do you think is more reliable?

Comment: The linux set up, almost certainly. Plus it's easy to set it up with apache, shorewall, soap, some sort of email server, etc etc just by installing some packages and doing minor config. It also occurs to me that even after setting up load balancing on windows you still have to do the net sharing, which could be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

RJFalconer is right, but you should know that if you do this, no *single* TCP connection will be able to get more than 256kBps. It's much like SMP in that manner.

You may also run into trouble with (web) applications and protocols that assume every user has a single IP address at any one time. If you can replace the two connections with a single faster one, that would be vastly preferable.